# Spring Data JPA: having mandatory and optional fields in query by example

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

Is there a way in the query by example to specify which field condition needs to be fulfilled and which one not?

If I have an entity:

```
   @Entity
    public class Person extends EntityBase {
    @Size(max = 50)
    @NotNull
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 80)
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    private Status status;
   }
```

Is there a way that I query all persons that have a specific status and either firstName or lastName equal to something?

Something like status = Active AND (firstName = "name" OR lastName = "name")

If I do:

```
Example<Person> example = Example.of(new Person("name", "name", Status.Active));
repo.findAll(example);
```

I have possiblity with the matchers to specify whether all fields should match or any field should match, can I do combination?
If it's not possible with query by example, what other way do you recommend?

Comment: Maybe create your own specific query with `@Query`.

Comment: I would like to avoid writing explicit queries if possible because I need to do similar for different entities, but yeah if nothing else works...

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods

Answer (score 0):

Repository.java

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
  List<Person> findByStatusAndFirstNameOrLastName(Status status, String firstName, String lastName);
}
```

PersonService.java

```
@Service
public class PersonService{

@Autowired
PersonRepository repo;

public List<Person> findByStatusAndFirstNameOrLastName(){
     repo.findByStatusAndFirstNameOrLastName(Status.Active,"name","name");
 }

}
```